# Is there a short way to store image variable?

Tags: javascript

I would like to find a shorter way of storing an image and its source in a variable.

Something that looks like:

```
ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
```

but for:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "image.png";
```

Can this be done in a single clean line like the first example?

Comment: Two lines to load an image is pretty short.

Comment: `(new Image()).src = 'image.png';`

Comment: create a new function (class) for yourself?

Comment: @Matt how are you assigning this image to a variable?

Comment: @Aesthete Yeah it is but I'm lazy, and I like shorthand. And I think you do var img = (new Image()).src = 'image.png'; , just a guess without trying.

Comment: @hustlerinc - Fair enough, the function below by T.J is what you want then.

Comment: @hustlerinc - Matt's question doesn't work, and if you try ` img = (new Image()).src = 'image.png';` you will end up with a variable `img` with a value of `image.png` - not and image object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're basically asking if the `Image` constructor can accept the URL as an argument. The answer is no. Of course, you can write a function:

```
function createImage(src) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = src;
    return img;
}
```

...and then use it:

```
var img = createImage("image.png");
```

If you ever want to use the `load` event on these images, your function will have to support it, because hooking `load` on the returned `Image` is not reliable. (There's a race condition, the browser can fire the `load` event after `src` is set but before you hook the event — yes, even though JavaScript itself is single-threaded on browsers.) That could look like this:

```
function createImage(src, loadHandler) {
    var img = new Image();
    if (loadHandler) {
        img.load = loadHandler;
    }
    img.src = src;
    return img;
}
```

...and then use it:

```
var img = createImage("image.png");             // No `load` handler
// or
var img = createImage("image.png", handler);    // Using a `load` handler
// or
var img = createImage("image.png", function() { // Using an inline `load` handler
    // ...the image loaded...
});
```

Comment: Awesome, just what I wanted. I'll accept as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

You could also new an object with [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create/) instead of `new`, then you could do it with:

```
var img = Object.create(Image.prototype, {src: {value: "image.png"}});
```

Comment: You could. The odds of it working well cross-browser are low (not least because you never actually call the constructor), and it [certainly doesn't work on Chrome](http://jsbin.com/ozirus).

Answer (score -3):

or you can simply write `var myImage = "<img src='../images/myImage.jpg'>";`